# download nltk data in aws lambda from python code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nltk

I am trying to dowloand nltk data in AWS lambda from python code. But It says

```
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'layers'",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 850, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datadog_lambda/handler.py\", line 30, in <module>\n    handler_module = import_module(modified_mod_name)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 850, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/entrypoints/__init__.py\", line 14, in <module>\n    from utils.container import state_machine\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/utils/container.py\", line 10, in <module>\n    from service_layer.models.nltk_downloader import is_nltk_data_download\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/service_layer/models/nltk_downloader.py\", line 12, in <module>\n    nltk.download(\"punkt\", download_dir=environ[\"LAMBDA_NLTK_DATA\"])\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/nltk/downloader.py\", line 777, in download\n    for msg in self.incr_download(info_or_id, download_dir, force):\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/nltk/downloader.py\", line 642, in incr_download\n    yield from self._download_package(info, download_dir, force)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/nltk/downloader.py\", line 699, in _download_package\n    os.makedirs(download_dir)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/os.py\", line 215, in makedirs\n    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/os.py\", line 225, in makedirs\n    mkdir(name, mode)\n"
  ]
}
```

Here is my code

```
        nltk.download("punkt", download_dir=download_dir)
        nltk.download("wordnet", download_dir=download_dir)
        nltk.download("omw-1.4", download_dir=download_dir)
```

I tried with a different download_dir option. But Nothing worked. For example,

```
download_dir = /layers/nltk_data
download_dir = nltk_data
etc
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is ephemeral storage in `/tmp` available for the lambda.  For more permanent storage, you may consider writing to S3 or EFS.

Answer (score 1):

You can only write to folder `/tmp`. It's default is 512Mb, but you can increase it to 10Gb in General configuration.
But it isn't good idea for storage large file, because every time cold start, it need download again.

You can try use File system, Mount the efs for lambda